# Database insert data

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I receive data in webservice and insert in sqlite database Android but if filed is empty repeat before filed As far as new filed no empty and repeat ...
please help me:

```java
public class gfc extends AsyncTask {

    private String Link = "";
    private String Count = "";
    private String tid = "";
    private String tim = "";
    private String tuser = "";
    private String tusername = "";
    private String tmatn = "";
    private String tcomments = "";
    private String tlikes = "";
    private String tdate = "";
    private String tip_addr = "";
    private database db;

    public gfc(String link, String count, Context c) {
        Link = link;
        Count = count;
        db = new database(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("count", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Count, "UTF8");

            URL mylink = new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            db.open();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                int f = 0;
                int c = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                    if (line.charAt(i) == '|') {
                        String temp = line.substring(f, i);
                        if (c == 0) {
                            tid = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 1) {
                            tdate = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 2) {
                            tuser = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 3) {
                            tusername = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 4) {
                            tip_addr = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 5) {
                            tcomments = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 6) {
                            tlikes = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 7) {
                            tim = temp;
                        }
                        if (c == 8) {
                            tmatn = temp.replace("^", "\n");
                        }

                        c += 1;
                        f = i + 1;
                    }
                }

                db.insert(tid, tuser, tusername, tmatn, tcomments, tlikes, tdate, tip_addr, tim);
                sb.append("t");
            }

            db.close();
            index.res = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you review the english? I have difficulties to understand the problem

Comment: filed == database  column

Comment: http://8pic.ir/images/ydchzktij6nxy9l9nsco.png